# Could this change in Itinerary for Schengen Visa cause problems?

Tags: schengen, transit, schengen-visas, itineraries

I was granted a type C Schengen Visa from France for a short stay in Paris. My original itinerary was to stay in Paris for 3 days and leave for my third destination. However, due to some emergency, I would have to leave for my third destination and skip my stay in Paris.

Now, I found a route which is significantly cheaper than all other options I have. This route is as follows: My city - Paris - Amsterdam - Third Destination (Multi-city tickets; Would probably have to collect baggage and check in at each stop).

My question here is can I use my current visa to make this connection? I figured that this should be OK as France would still be my main destination and I'm not extending my stay. However, I still have doubts as I wouldn't be anywhere close to my original itinerary.

Comment: Is your  "third destination" within the Schengen area? Is seems that in your revised itinerary, you won't be staying in France at all. Is that correct?

Comment: Both my city and the third destination are outside schengen area. In my revised itinerary, I’d be staying in the whole schengen area for one day. I would fly to paris, take a flight from paris to amsterdam and leave from amsterdam on the same day. I figured if i’d be only spending few hours in both Paris and Amsterdam and will be landing in paris, my main destination would in Schengen area would still be Paris.

Comment: The Schengen agreement requires visas to be applied-for from the "main destination." If the a main destination cannot be ascertained, the application must be filed with the Schengen country first to be entered. See Article 12.2 at https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:42000A0922(02) Here, your itinerary has changed, but your visa was fortuitously obtained from the country of your first entry. This isn't posted as an Answer, as I have no  first-hand experience with this issue. That said, I _think_ this will be found acceptable and you will be allowed entry into France.